# How to get program to restart without using break?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
answer = input('how are you')
if answer == 'good':
    print('glad to hear it')
if answer == 'what?':
    print('how are you?')
```

Without using break, how do I start at the beginning again if the user were to input 'what?' How would I do this with only variables and loops?

Comment: Recursion, a loop, etc are all ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

''' it keeps looping till the answer is .good. No flags are used '''

```
 answer='#'
 while(answer != 'good'):
     answer = input('how are you\n') 
     if answer == 'good':
         print('glad to hear it')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work properly:

```
good = False

while not good:
    answer = input('how are you?')
    if answer == 'what?':
        continue

    if answer == 'good':
        good = True
        print('glad to hear it')
```

When the variable `good` becomes `True`, the loop stops. The `continue` skips to the next iteration of the loop, but, it's not necessary. Leaving it there shows the reader that `'what?'` is an expected input.

Now, you said you can't use `break`, but, if you could, it would look like this:

```
while True:
    answer = input('how are you?')
    if answer == 'what?':
        continue

    if answer == 'good':
        print('glad to hear it')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything complicated to achieve that.

```
input = '' #nothing in input
while input != 'good': #true the first time
  input = raw_input('how are you?') #assign user input to input
if input == 'good': #if it's good print message
  print('glad to hear it')
```

or

```
input = 'what?' #what? in input
while input == 'what?': #true the first time
  input = raw_input('how are you?') #assign user input to input
if input == 'good': #if it's good print message
  print('glad to hear it')
else:
  print('too bad')
```

The first case if you're expecting `good` or the second if any reply works except `what?`.